# Bot status changes temporary

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have PresenceUpdate Set so when a specific user streams the bot status updates and it announces in the channel. It did announce and it worked fine but the bot status seems to change for only ~20 seconds then it would go back to its default.

I've tried fixing it using:

- For Loop
- While Loop
- Recursion function

Can anyone help me out and fix this? Here is my code:

```
client.on("presenceUpdate", (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
  let announcement = "Announcement Message";
  if (!newPresence.activities) return false;
  newPresence.activities.forEach(activity => {
      if (activity.type == "STREAMING") {
        if(newPresence.user.id == "ID OF USER STREAMING") {
          console.log(`${newPresence.user.tag} is streaming at ${activity.url}.`);
          client.channels.cache.get("My Channel ID").send(announcement);
          client.user.setActivity("to the server", { type: "STREAMING",  url: "Twitch Link"});
       };
      };
  });
});
```

**EDIT:** Okay so i managed to fix it by removing the part where if they r not streaming the status returns to default. HOWEVER, now it is stuck on streaming even when the user is no longer streaming. How do i solve this? The code has been also updated.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the streaming user's id somewhere, and then check whenever the presence is update if it is this same user.

Here is an example :

```js
if (client.streamingUserID !== undefined && client.streamingUserID !== newPresence.user.id) return;
newPresence.activities.forEach(activity => {
    if (activity.type == "STREAMING") {
        if(newPresence.user.id == "ID OF USER STREAMING") { 
            console.log(`${newPresence.user.tag} is streaming at ${activity.url}.`);
            client.channels.cache.get("My Channel ID").send(announcement);
            client.user.setActivity("to the server", { type: "STREAMING", url: "Twitch Link"});
            client.streamingUserID = newPresence.user.id;
        }; 
    } else {
        // set back activity to default and
        delete client.streamingUserID;
    }
});
```

Comment: There was an error in the first if statement and i had to change `!===` to `!==`. And Now im just waiting for the streamer to come online to see if it works. I will update you asap.

Comment: @JustCVhilling woops sorry, small typo here ^^'

Comment: It doesn't work, the status just disappears now and doesn't set it to streaming mode or anything. i just want to be able to have it on stream mode and when the user stops streaming it stops too

Comment: @JustCVhilling Actually, I was wondering why you were making use of a forEach loop ? Why not just grab the first activity, and do your stuff ? By the way I may have added a fix in my last edit

Comment: I asked a question recently to update the code for the presenceupdate. you can find it on my page and that's the code i was using if there is a better method to just detect that specific user that would be better instead of me having to use the forEach loop.

Comment: I have also just updated the code, and now i'm just waiting on the streamer to test it out. since we're in different time zones. as soon as i get the results ill add another comment.

Comment: Okay so now it updates the status of the bot to streaming but its just stuck on there when the user changes their status to online normally or offline or idle or dnd